# why we use interface as abstract class also doing same?

Tags: c#, oop

In my project I have all virtual methods.so I can declare it in abstract class or in interface.But Why we user interface as same we can do with abstract?

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Virtual methods isn't good enough, they need to be *abstract* methods.  Burning up the one-and-only base class that a .NET class can inherit from isn't usually that desirable.

Comment: @Polity: "Specious" means "this looks correct but actually contains a subtle error", as in, "your argument is specious". I think you meant "species".

Comment: @EricLippert A subtle but fundamental error, I stand corrected!

Answer (score 4):

An interface looks like a class, but has no implementation.

-The only thing it contains are declarations of events, indexers, methods and/or properties.

-The reason interfaces only provide declarations is because they are inherited by classes and structs, which must provide an implementation for each interface member declared.

Interfaces in C# are provided as a replacement of **multiple inheritance.**

-**Because C# does not support multiple inheritance**, it was necessary to incorporate some other method so that the class can inherit the behavior of more than one class, avoiding the problem of name ambiguity that is found in C++.

-With name ambiguity, the object of a class does not know which method to call if the two base classes of that class object contain the same named method.

Purposes of Interfaces

-create loosely coupled software

-support design by contract (an implementor must provide the entire interface)

-allow for pluggable software

-allow different objects to interact easily

-hide implementation details of classes from each other

-facilitate reuse of software

Comment: All of the above listed advantages are also provided- or could be provided with abstract classes. A good argument for offering interfaces can be found in the link provided by Chris Sinclair. Interfaces simply have a different purpose then abstract classes. Although possible, you wouldnt ram a screw with a hammer

Comment: please can u provide that link?

Comment: Interface defines a contract. An Abstract base class defines a behavior.

Essentially, you can provide a single class that implements multiple interfaces, which then in turn can be injected into multiple classes, but you will only have a single abstract base class (at least in C#).

Consider the point of registering a type at the container (the composition root at best) and consider the point where you resolve the dependency (the constructor or a property).

Answer (score 2):

Abstract classes allow **some** implementation to serve as a basis. Interfaces also allow multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

If text isn't helping you then let me give you an example, recently I created a collection of controls that all inhertited from other controls that shared a common function `UnitChanged()` (which did a different thing for each).

```
public MyTextBox : TextBox
public MyComboBox : ComboBox
public MyLabel : Label
```

When I needed to call this function, it needed to change all labels, textboxes, and comboboxes
now if I didnt use an interface I would have to do

```
foreach(MyTextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<MyTextBox>())
    tb.UnitChanged();
foreach(MyComboBox cb in this.Controls.OfType<MyComboBox >())
    cb.UnitChanged();
foreach(MyLabel lab in this.Controls.OfType<MyLabel>())
    lab.UnitChanged();
```

now with an interface

```
foreach(IMyInterface control in this.Controls.OfType<IMyInterface >())
    control.UnitChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

driven classes can implements multi interface, but only each driven class can inherits from one classs